# Distribution adding two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

So consider two random variables $X$ and $Y$ with PDF's $f_X$ and $f_Y$.
When both are independent the PDF of $X+Y$ simply becomes the convolution product $f_X*f_Y$.

However what if these are not independent? Is there some alternate formula one can turn to, possibly using the conditional PDF of $Y$ wrt $X$?
If no such clear cut answer exist, are there general approaches one can use to find the PDF $f_{X+Y}$?

Comment: With independence you have $f_{X+Y}(z)  = \int f_{Y}(z-x)\, f_X(x)\, dx$.  Without independence you have  
$f_{X+Y}(z)  = \int f_{Y\mid X}(z-x\mid x)\, f_X(x)\, dx$

Comment: Oh, just that simple. Great thx :)